# How do I compare two tables data?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Hi I do have an old table and new table with same index/data. TABLE1 and TABLE2

but TABLE1 has got more data than TABLE2. this was maintained by some one and I dont know how this happened. so my question is how do I compare these two table and find which data is TABLE2 missing?? there is almost 200000 datas there so manually doing is not possible...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution without nested query:

```
select TABLE1.id from TABLE1 left join TABLE2 on TABLE1.id = TABLE2.id where TABLE2.id is null
```

Answer (score 1):

in PHP:

http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php

in SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE id {NOT} IN ( SELECT id FROM TABLE2 )
```

depending on criteria of comparison

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE1 t1 WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM TABLE2 WHERE t1.id == t2.id)
```

Comment: can you explain this little bit??

Comment: @mathew: Here I select the tubes in TABLE1 if there's no tube with the same id in TABLE2. I think you should provides more information about 2 tables. In here, I assume that your 2 tables is with the same fields & structure. But it seems (from your comments) that it's not quite right.

Comment: ok will explain..both tables are same. what I am looking is both table contains user details so I want find which are the users missing in table2

Comment: @mathew: well, now it's more clearer. I think you should update the question for others to see, and please give an example (add some main fields of the table).

Answer (score 0):

By same index I am hoping you mean they share a primary key?

SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE username NOT IN (SELECT username FROM TABLE2)

Comment: ok i edited.  basially you want to see the rows in TABLE1 for whuich TABLE2 does not have a row with that username, right?